# is it possible to install perf on ubuntu with kernel 5.4.39?

Tags: 20.04

I want to install `perf` on ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.4.39.

The problem is that I'm getting

```
root@xxx:/home# perf

WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.4.39

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.4.39-linuxkit
    linux-cloud-tools-5.4.39-linuxkit

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-linuxkit
    linux-cloud-tools-linuxkit
```

and then when I try to install those packages it's say:

```
E: Unable to locate package
```

Comment: Old kernel packages are removed from the repositories. We are on version 5.4.0-52-generic, so what is wrong with it?

Comment: @mikewhatever I'm on 5.4.0-56-generic (20.04.01) and have the same issue. When I type `perf`, it complains and suggests to install nonexistent linux-tools-5.4.0-56-generic and co. If I just install linux-tools-generic/common, the "not found" error doesn't go away.

Comment: You could try to install `linux-tools-generic`, also, I can't find a package named `perf` in the repositories. Perhaps `gtkperf` or something else, otherwise, not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic linux-tools-`uname -r`
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm getting the same output : 
root@xxx:/home/anchorage_network_mgt/build# apt-get install --reinstall linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic linux-tools-`uname -r`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.4.39-linuxkit
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-5.4.39-linuxkit'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-5.4.39-linuxkit'

Comment: Worked perfectly to get `perf` to run on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Thank you very much!

Comment: Worked for me as well, as I understand it this apt command directs it to install the appropriate version (uname -r) of these packages, i.e. the one matching your kernel libraries version, from what I gather from the outputs of the apt install with and without the use of `uname -r` there. But I could use some further confirmation about that.